# Entity Framework and views

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, view

I am using EF 4 and have used the "Update Model from Database" option to import a view into the model.

What I would like to be able to do now is choose "Generate Database from Model" and have EF script out the view correctly.  My experience is that it creates a table instead of a view.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that this is possible in the current version. The code first is still in its first version.

It would be one thing to tell EF that these fields map to a view, however you would also need to tell EF which tables the fields in the view came from.

Comment: I was hoping that when you added a view from the database that Ef would have some way to inspect the view and cache the SQL for it.  Then it would be able to reproduce the view when you updated the database from code.  This would be a stellar feature.  Too bad it doesnt exist. :(